# group policy being applied from offsite Domain Controller: why?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, group-policy

**Site 2**: I have a small branch with 1 DC and 4 clients.

**Site 1**: Meanwhile my main branch has 2 DCs and lots of clients.

I made some GP changes on `DC-site2`, and I was wondering why they weren't applying to the clients at `site2`.

Well I did a `gpresult /r` and it showed that both `Computer Settings` and `User Settings` were coming from `DC-site1.DOMAIN.COM`.  WHY?

I did `echo %logonserver%`.  Result: `DC-site2`.  Good so far.
I did `set log` (kind of redundant).  Result: `DC-site2`.  Still looking good.
`nltest /dsgetsite`.  Result: `site2`.  Ok, so the client knows it is in the right site.
`nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com /Account:client-pc1$`.  Result: `DC: \\DC-site2.DOMAIN.COM`.  Still good!

What the hell?

I checked Active Directory Sites and Services, and *ONLY* the `DC-site2` server is showed listed in `site2`.
I checked DNS settings, and in `Forward Lookup Zones -> _msdcs.domain.com -> dc -> _sites -> site2` I *ONLY* see entries for the `DC-site2` server.

And yet, `gpresult /r` on this client still shows it is applying GP from the `DC-site1` server.  WHY?

This was last night.  This morning I checked again and the same machine is getting `Computer Settings` from `DC-site2` but `User Settings` from `DC-site1`.  WHY?

Comment: Run `nltest /dsgetsitecov` on each DC and post the results in your question.

Comment: done.  On the `dc-site1` server, result is `site1` as expected and nothing else.  `The command completed successfully`.  Similarly, `dc-site2` server shows result of `site2` only and `completed successfully`.